# Need to remove "Generated by maven-plugin-tools 3.5 on 2021-01-20" text from mvn generated plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

The plugin.xml file contains this commented text  whenever I build the plugin using maven-plugin-tool .

How can I get rid of this as I don't want this information?

Comment: What is the problem with that because it's simply the truth..

Comment: Because "Truth is Bitter" !!... Do we have a solution? ...the date part is causing the issue as it will be different if build on two separate dates without any change.

Comment: What exactly is causing the issue? Why do you build several times? Do you don't make a release of your plugin to get a reliable state of your plugin? Please show a full example...